# MSCRM 2013 IFD Organization Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs

I've issue with IFD configuration of my crm organization.
When I try to access to public address https://organization.domain.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationService.svc?wsdl browser redirect to ADFS page for credentials and I would like view WSDL directly, because the CRM plugin for outlook doesn't work.
ADFS is version 3.0 and uses WAP (new ADFS Proxy for 3.0) for exposing STS on internet.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by setting pre-authentication pass-through on WAP / ADFS Proxy